# fullCalendar 2.2.5 formatDate

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am upgrading `fullCalendar` from 1.6 to 2.2.5

I get the following error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'formatDate'
```

In the following script:

```
dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#eventDate').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
    $('#eventTime').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'HH:mm'));
},
```

Comment: In your browser tools, have you ensured `date` is in fact a Date object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Guide on upgrading to version 2](http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/) says that `$.fullCalendar.formatDate` method has been changed.

Use a moment's `.format()` method instead of `$.fullCalendar.formatDate`

Comment: Thank you. I changed to: $('#eventDate').val().format('dd/MM/yyyy');

Get this error:Object doesn't support property or method 'format'

Comment: Are you sure that moment.js is being included? Please read the guide I've linked and see which parts you forgot to change (like the `formatDate`).

Comment: I have moment.js included.  The document shows moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); but there is no example on how to change a $('#eventDate').

Comment: Open the guide and search for `dayClick` you can see it has been affected in version 2.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the correct documentation.  Is there any example for using version 2.5 in MVC/Json.

Comment: Could not really figure it out so I went back to 1.6.  Thanks